# Can't install KDE desktop environment in FreeBSD 12

Tags: raspberry-pi, freebsd, kde-plasma-5

So i have booted my **Raspberry Pi 3 B+** today with a FreeBSD 12 image file and started **configuring it to have a desktop graphical UI**.

As i have tried to install KDE with the following command,

```
# pkg install x11/kde5
```

got this error massage:

```
pkg: No packages available to install matching 'x11/kde5' have been found in the repositories.
```

Do anyone has a solution? Or can someone help me to find out what am I doing wrong (since I'm not an experienced user)?

Hints:
- I was doing the process according to the step by step guide on the [official freeBSD handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/x11-wm.html#x11-wm-kde).
- I also googled the problem, but I couldn't find an answer. This issue seems to be new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find an answer. This question is closed.
I solved the problem by trying another OS. But you can still post your answers here for users who may face this problem in the future and reach this question. Never is too late to answer a question.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the package is not in the [latest repository](http://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:12:amd64/latest/All/), but it is in [the quarterly](http://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:12:amd64/quarterly/All/).

So you can switch back to the quarterly (changing *latest* for *quarterly* in the URL from the configuration file `/etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf`) and install the package normally.

But remember that switching between repositories might cause compatibility problems, so if after that system complaints about different QT versions, you should repair it force-updating the conflicting packages or the safer option:

```
sudo pkg upgrade -f
```